# TypeError: NoneType is unsubscriptable - IF statement

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, typeerror, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to find fuzzy string matches for university names and print a certain score (10, 5 ,3) to a csv each time depending on what list the closest match came from.

```
data = [["MIT"], ["Stanford"], ...]

Data1 = ['MASSACHUSETTS INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY (MIT)'], ['STANFORD UNIVERSITY'],...
```

So far I have tried:

```
1 for uni in data:
2    hit = process.extractOne(str(uni[0]), data1, scorer = fuzz.token_set_ratio, score_cutoff = 90)
3    if float(hit[1]) < 100:
4       print("not found")
5    else:
        print("Closest match for " + str(uni[0]) + " is " + str(hit[0]) " + "score: 10")
```

At this point I get the `TypeError: NoneType is unsubscriptable` for line 3

I have checked the type of my variable:

```
print(type(hit)) #I was getting tuple now NoneType...
print(len(hit))  # Was getting 2 now unsubscriptable
print(float(hit[1])) # 100
```

As I understood this error comes up when a variable is not the type one thinks it is. Any idea how to resolve this issue? Many thanks

Thanks to @inthevortex, I was able to complete the code as follows:

```
for uni in data:
hit = process.extractOne(str(uni[0]), data10, scorer = fuzz.token_set_ratio, score_cutoff = 90)
try:
    if float(hit[1]) >= 94:
        with open(filename, mode='a', newline="") as csv_file:
            fieldnames = ['bwbnr', 'uni_name', 'match', 'points']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=';')
            writer.writerow({'bwbnr': str(uni[0]), 'uni_name': str(uni[0]), 'match': str(hit), 'points': 10})

except:
    hit1 = process.extractOne(str(uni[0]), data11, scorer = fuzz.token_set_ratio, score_cutoff = 90)
    try:
        if float(hit1[1]) >= 94:
            with open(filename, mode='a', newline="") as csv_file:
                fieldnames = ['bwbnr', 'uni_name', 'match', 'points']
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=';')
                writer.writerow({'bwbnr': str(uni[0]), 'uni_name': str(uni[0]), 'match': str(hit1), 'points': 5})
```

... and so on... until the last except.

Comment: You can try using `try` and `except` statements to handle the exceptions.

Comment: @inthevortex Thanks. Yeah, I see now that when he doesn't find a match, the problem occurs. That's a great help already. I will see if I can move on from there!

Comment: try it out, let me know if you face any more difficulties. :)

Comment: I think the problem is on the if statement `if float(hit[1]) < 100:`at some point `hint[1]`becomes `None`and you cannot compare a `None Type`with an `integer`. Therefore, add a new line `if hit[1]:` to make sure it exists before comparing it with 0

Comment: Maybe I am missing something - but `for uni in data:` will loop through your `data` list and return the entries - i.e. `uni` will contain an element of the list. `uni[1]` will contain the second letter of the element. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Mortz I am using `uni[1]` because it is a list of lists (to do with the csv file). The university names are always the second element in the inner lists. The idea is to compare that string `uni[1]` with the `data1` list and 12 more lists. I cannot do it with one big list, as I need to know which list `uni[1]` was found in to alot it the correct score (not the fuzzy score, one I choose myself).

Comment: @Uralan - Okay, the first code line in your question though `data = ["MIT", "Stanford",...]` doesn't indicate that `data` is a list of lists

Comment: @Mortz Absolutely right. My bad! Corrected it now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @inthevortex I completed the code using the try-except method:

```
for uni in data:
hit = process.extractOne(str(uni[0]), data10, scorer = fuzz.token_set_ratio, score_cutoff = 90)
try:
   if float(hit[1]) >= 94:
       with open(filename, mode='a', newline="") as csv_file:
           fieldnames = ['bwbnr', 'uni_name', 'match', 'points']
           writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=';')
           writer.writerow({'bwbnr': str(uni[0]), 'uni_name': str(uni[0]), 'match': str(hit), 'points': 10})

except:
hit1 = process.extractOne(str(uni[0]), data11, scorer = fuzz.token_set_ratio, score_cutoff = 90)
try:
    if float(hit1[1]) >= 94:
        with open(filename, mode='a', newline="") as csv_file:
            fieldnames = ['bwbnr', 'uni_name', 'match', 'points']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=';')
            writer.writerow({'bwbnr': str(uni[0]), 'uni_name': str(uni[0]), 'match': str(hit1), 'points': 5})
```

All the way down to the last list I wanted to compare with, again with try-except!